# SolveAlways set

Tags: equation-solving

I have a `SolveAlways` command:

```
SolveAlways[x==1,y]
```

(This is a minimal solution, the acutal one is a lot harder)

The output is

```
{{x->1}}
```

With that, I want to set x=1. (This, being a minimal example, has only one solution x, but in my harder example I have 5; and I don't want to keep typing out x1=1,x2=2,x3=3 every time the solution changes.

How to?

Thanks

Comment: P.S. I'm a 4-hour-freshling to mathematica, but am otherwise proficient in matlab and js

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea to use separate variables for your equation solving and for assignment, in case you make mistakes. So if you have a result like `res = {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}}`, then you could do something like `xsol = x /. res`.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! Thank you! and thanks for the tip about best practice, turns out it was pretty useful too

Comment: And then you can access the particular values using [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), e.g. `xsol[[1]]` will be `1` etc.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999